# How do CGI scripts know the IP address of the requestor?

Tags: http, networking, tcp, cgi

CGI scripts can access the IP address of the source host using the REMOTE_ADDR variable. But CGI exists on the application layer, so how does it know network layer information? If you look at HTTP headers in Postman, they don't give you this info, so how do CGI scripts get it?

Answer (score 0):

Your server APACHE or other, receives HTTP information, it sets up environment variables from what it received, environment variables are available to CGI scripts or programs. If POSTMAN does not give you what you want a small C program or any other language will give you that info. But REMOTE_ADDR is not a reliable information to uniquely identify your user, if that is what you have in mind. I don't know anything about POSTMAN so cannot help there.